# Feign client for multiple services

Tags: netflix-feign

I have a SpringBoot server that offers multiple services under multiple REST controllers. So I have something like:

- /serviceA/api1
- /serviceA/api2
- /serviceB/api1
- /serviceB/api2

I want to use **1** Feign client to access them. But I don't really put all these calls in 1 'flat' interface. So I do not want to have:

```
public interface Client {
    @RequestLine(value="GET /serviceA/api1")
    public String getServiceAapi1();

    @RequestLine(value="GET /serviceA/api2")
    public String getServiceBapi2();

    @RequestLine(value="GET /serviceB/api1")
    public String getServiceAapi1();

    @RequestLine(value="GET /serviceB/api2")
    public String getServiceBapi2();
}
```

I'm looking for a way so that at runtime I can use:

```
client.serviceA().api1();
client.serviceA().api2();
client.serviceB().api1();
client.serviceB().api2();
```

Any way to do this?

I hope this request makes sense ;-).

Thanks.

Henry

Answer (score 0):

You can use the param option and with java 8, the interfaces are enabled to use the default method, so you could implement something like next:

```
@RequestLine(value="GET /serviceA/{api}")
public String getServiceApi(@Param("api") String api);

default String api1() {
   return getServiceApi("api1");
}

default String api2() {
   return getServiceApi("api2");
}
```

---

The structure you want cannot be created by the feign client at runtime, you have to create a structure like next by yourself:

```
public class Client {

    private final ServiceA serviceA;
    private final ServiceB serviceB;

    public Client(ServiceA serviceA, ServiceB serviceB) {
        this.serviceA = serviceA;
        this.serviceB = serviceB;
    }

    public ServiceA serviceA() {
        return serviceA;
    }

    public ServiceB serviceB() {
        return serviceB;
    }

    interface ServiceA {
        @RequestLine(value="GET /serviceA/api1")
        public String api1();

        @RequestLine(value="GET /serviceA/api2")
        public String api2();
    }

    interface ServiceB {
        @RequestLine(value="GET /serviceB/api1")
        public String api1();

        @RequestLine(value="GET /serviceB/api2")
        public String api2();
    }
}
```